# Will installing gedit  also installs a GUI  as a dependency in server?

Tags: server, apt, gedit

I want to use `gedit` using ssh for file editing on my server. I use `nano`, but for html and css `gedit` is better.

Now with `sudo apt-get install gedit` I get dependencies that are 120mb, that kind seems too big.

So did I just install also a complete user interface because of `gedit`? I don't need a user interface... What did it also install automatically? Should I've used some other command for installation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find what a package depends on using `apt-rdepends`, install it with Software Center:

[image: Install via the software center]

Or with terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install apt-rdepends
```

To check what packages depends `gedit` on (packages that were installed when you did `sudo apt-get install gedit`) type this after you installed apt-rdepends

```
sudo apt-rdepends gedit
```

That will return the list of packages that `gedit` installed or were already installed and are used by gedit for running.

If you want to use `gedit` there will be a lot of dependencies that you wont be able to avoid but are necessary for the program to run without faults.

Comment: Latest installing Gedit doesn't work with apt-get, so how to install it manually by `./configure` type thing ?

Answer (score 2):

You most likely did not actually install X11 or anything like that, however, you probably have lots of GTK+ libs and other related junk on your system.  If you change your mind, you can execute the following commands to remove Gedit and its depedencies, without breaking anything else:

```
sudo apt-get remove gedit
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

This will remove any packages which apt-get installed automatically and which are no longer needed.

If you want to use something better than nano, try using [sftp](http://enwp.org/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol) to download the file, edit it in your editor of choice, and then upload it again.  If you have OpenSSH as the SSH server this may be available without reconfiguring anything or installing additional software.

Comment: u were right. Not very convenient using x11. Anyhow, I uninstalled, and shared folder with samba, so I can edit them like a local folder :) thanks.